# asp.net Update Panels and postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, postback

I have a DDL and Button which when clicked create a dynamic table; all controls are within an `UpdatePanel`.

Outside the panel I have 2 buttons which should be hidden until the table is created.
If the buttons start as `visible = false` and then I set them to true after I click the GO button from the `UpdatePanel`, they never become visible

If I add a second UpdatePanel and put the 2 buttons in there it sort of works but I always get this error when clicking on either button:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: 
The message received from the server could not be parsed.
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the two Buttons inside Update Panel. Only controls in the update panel get updated in an Ajax call. That is, if you want to alter any control's state through codebehind in an Ajax call you will have to include it inside your Update panel. You cannot change controls outside Update panel in an Ajax call.

**UPDATE** 
You need event handlers for this. Make the Button visible=true; and set their visibility:hidden, then change them as below when your call is completed.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(beginRequestHandle);
      Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandle);
      function beginRequestHandle(sender, Args) {
      //Do something when call begins.
        }

function endRequestHandle(sender, Args) {
document.getElementById("Button1").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("Button2").style.visibility = "visible";
}
      </script>
```

Comment: That breaks the EPPlus calls to save contents to excel file so I need them outside. Is there a way to create them with JS perhaps, or whats another way to show/hide buttons without updating the page?

Comment: Updated my answer have a look.

Comment: Almost got it. I get this since its an asp:button Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'style': object is null or undefined How to change the above?

Comment: already done: <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="SUBMIT" Visible="true" Width="200px" Font-Bold="True"/> still happens

Comment: Set the style visible:hidden to the buttons in the CSS.

Comment: The exact same happens: <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="SUBMIT" style="visibility:hidden" Width="200px" Font-Bold="True"/> and document.getElementById("Button1").style.visibility = "visible"; the annoying thing is that is works for <input> so its a syntax issue for sure

Comment: Oops didn't see that Add this ClientIDMode="Static"

Answer (score 0):

Yes like Ashwin told you have to make the button visible from JS if you need the buttons outside the update panel. If you have scriptmanager in your page then you can call the JS function which make the buttons visible from codebehind like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   function showButtons(){
     document.getElementById("<%= Button1.ClientID %>").style.visibility = "visible";
     document.getElementById("<%= Button2.ClientID %>").style.visibility = "visible";
   }
</script>
```

If the button is a server control then get the client id of the button using the code block <%= %>. In the codebehind after creating the dynamic table  use this

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "showButtons", "showButtons();", true);
```

Comment: would the same work for a label? I can't seem to get that one to do the same.

Comment: It was getting its text added after the postback so its fine now.